# How to loop on queue of promises (serialize async messages)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, deferred

I have a queue of promises (representing msgs) which I need to process in order.
I'm using angularJS.

For the sake of the example suppose I have `connect()` which returns a promise for the connection and then `msgQueue` which is a `JavaScript` array of promises, each representing a msg.

I would start by doing this:

```
connect().then(function(){
    return msgQueue.dequeue();
});

// Async Loop on all msgs... How?
```

I'm sort of a Defer/Promise newbie so bear with me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function serializeAsynch(queue,operate) {
  var msg = queue.dequeue();
  if (msg) msg.then(function(data) { operate(data); serializeAsynch(queue); });
}

connect().then(function() { serializeAsynch(msgQueue,process); });
```

I think that will work.  We're waiting for `connect` to resolve, then passing in the `msgQueue`.  We get the first message in the `queue` and set it's resolution handler to process the data and then recurse on the queue.  The recursion will dump out when there's nothing left in the queue.

Comment: Wouldn't a recursion solution cause a stack overflow (no pun intended) if there are too many messages?

Comment: I take my comment back - since it's asynchronous there is no actual recursion and no stack growth.

Comment: Programming in Erlang makes you think like this as a natural flow of a program. Can't believe I had to look this up, been a while since I've been in Erlang land I guess. :/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work. Assuming that `msgQueue.dequeue()` returns a promise.

```
function doWork(work) {
    work().then(function(data) {
       //process data
       msgQueue.dequeue().then(function(work) {
           doWork(work);
       });
    });
}
```